# Can abstract classes have arrays?

Tags: arrays, typescript, abstract-class

In typescript, is it possible to have an array inside an abstract class, then add or push an item in that array?

```typescript
abstract class Department {
  private data: string[] = [];

  addData(item: string) {
    this.data.push(item);
  }

  constructor(public name: string) {}

  printName(): void {
    console.log("Department name: " + this.name);
  }

  abstract printMeeting(): void;
}
```

Comment: I think the answer is probably "yes, you can" but you haven't really provided enough detail about what you're trying to accomplish.  Have you tried something and it didn't work?

Comment: i followed the documentation and i seem to be lost

Comment: Have you tried another set of documentation perhaps?

Comment: If you're new to Stack Overflow, you should read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you want useful answers, you should provide a [mcve] of your issue.  Otherwise you will get generic or less relevant answers than you want.

Comment: Specifically, you should post your code inside your question (which you can edit), not in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824356/in-typescript-abstract-classes-have-arrays#comment90603582_51824460).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. It's exactly like doing it in a non-`abstract` class, you just mark it `abstract`:

```
abstract class Example {
    private data: string[] = [];

    addData(item: string) {
        this.data.push(item);
    }
}
```

This won't be useful unless you subclass it (`class SomethingElse extends Example`...).

Comment: can you teach me how to do it, like my arrays are ketchup and mustard, then i want to add a new sauce and display the new sauce that was added

Comment: unexpected token, A constructor, medthod, accessor, or property was expected - the compiler says

Comment: @user2699595 - The above works just fine in TypeScript: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Example%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20data%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20addData(item%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.data.push(item)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D

Comment: abstract class Department {
 private data: string[] = [];
  addData(item: string) {
  this.data.push(item);
  }
   constructor(public name: string) {}
    printName(): void {
        console.log("Department name: " + this.name);
    }
    abstract printMeeting(): void; 
}

Comment: yes the above code works great, but i'm trying to follow the documentation, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html, abstract classes

Comment: @user2699595 - That code's fine too: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Department%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20data%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20addData(item%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.data.push(item)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20printName()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Department%20name%3A%20%22%20%2B%20this.name)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20printMeeting()%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D

Comment: i am having a headache, how do i use the addData() inside the subclass, the make a console.log(add a data here inside the array) ?